# pyinstaller replace strings like git archive

Tags: git, pyinstaller, git-archive

with `git archive` command, I can insert text in the source, example: if the code have the string

```
 # $Format:%cd$
```

the string is replaced by the commit date.

with pyinstaller and spec file, I can make come similar ? (update strings in building process)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a solution is a make file with the

```
# makefile
# update some string with git export
git archive ...
# pyinstaller in output directory of git export
pyinstaller file.spec
```

but, I try search a direct solution with pyinstaller.